# Add icon in jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using [docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) and works well however I can't seem to figure out how to add an icon to the headers of the accordion.

I only need to add the icon and I don't want to style the entire accordion. Anyone knows how? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your icon to replace the existing triangle icon, or do you want to add this elsewhere?

Comment: @Scrimothy There's no icon at all. Note that my code is just like this `$("#accordion").accordion();`, I think my question is more like what else do I need to put the default icons from jquery UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add it into your html inside the H3 tag as an image or as the background of a span tag maybe.

Alternatively you could add it as a background to the H3 tag via your stylesheet.

That's probably the two simplest options.

```
#accordion h3 {
    background: // image path etc here
}
```

WHen an H3 is open (i.e. it's the active H3) it gets a different class so you can use that to display a different icon.

```
#accordion h3.ui-state-active {
    background: // different image path here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you make the icons change when opening/closing the accordion?